# For loop not running

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
T = 2
AList = [[0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0]]
BList = [[1,2,4,2,3], [1,2,4,2,4]]

def magic(i):
    AList[t][i] = int(AList[t][i]) + 1
    AList[t][i+1] = int(AList[t][i+1]) + 2
    AList[t][i+2] = int(AList[t][i+2]) + 3

for t in range(T):
    nie = False
    for i in range(len(AList[t]) - 2):
        Diff = int(int(AList[t][i]) - int(BList[t][i]))
        if Diff > 0:
            print('NIE')
            nie = True
            break
        elif Diff == 0:
            pass
        else:
            for r in range(Diff): #Here, this loop doesn't work
                print('asd')
                magic(i)
```

The commented loop in the above code doesn't seem to be working.
Whenever I remove the loop and put the contents inside it outside the loop, it starts working again.
I have tried everything from changing it to a while loop to changing the if statements above it.
The loop I'm talking about is the third-last line of the code.

Comment: That block of code only runs if `Diff` is less than 0. `range(Diff)` ends up returning nothing so the for loop is never run. What exactly are you trying to accomplish there?

Comment: What do you expect `range(Diff)` to return on the first loop?

Comment: ohhhhh. I understand now. Thanks for your help. I am an idiot